# Upgrade to PHP7.1 and MPDF show error - A non-numeric value encountered at line 30648

Tags: mpdf

I'm using PHP 5.x and mPDF 6.x for long time.

This week I decide to upgrade system to PHP7.1 but still using mPDF6.

I face some problem after upgrading.

PROBLEM 1::

Console show error message: constructer with the same name as class name is deprecate.

> > I go through each php files and find classes, then replace constructer function with __construct(...)

PROBLEM 2::

Console show error message:: Can not assign property ID to $attr
I go to file mPDF.php in function MergeCSS(...). I add new line of code at third line.

> > if (empty($attr)) { $attr = array();}

PROBLEM 3::

Console show error message following this::
"A non-numeric value encountered" at line 30648."

My solution to solve this problem is just::

1. replace mPDF->ConvertSize() function in mPDF.php file with coding from MPDF7.

   > > By replace function ConvertSize() with function ConvertSize() and multiplyFontSize();

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/src/SizeConverter.php

2. Add constant to mPDF class

> > const SCALE = 72 / 25.4;

Hope this help for someone who face this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the 3rd solution

Answer (score 8):

For people who want a complete "A non-numeric value encountered" fix. Take a look at my forked repo of mpdf 6.1.3 with [commit](https://github.com/baselbers/mpdf/commit/5cbaff4303604247f698afc6b13a51987a58f5bc).

Answer (score 2):

FYI: PHP7 throws a compile-time error when it encounters a switch statement with multiple default blocks. mpdf uses multiple default blocks in its switch statements.

Answer (score 1):

I have version 8.0.0 and the same error.

My solution was: in the file src/SizeConverter.php on the line 79 i had:

```
case '%':
            if ($fontsize && $usefontsize) {
                $size *= $fontsize / 100;
            } else {
                $size *= $maxsize / 100;
            }
            break;
```

Change to:

```
case '%':
            if ($fontsize && $usefontsize) {
                $size *= $fontsize / 100;
            } else {
                $maxsize = \str_replace('mm', '', $maxsize);

                $size *= $maxsize / 100;
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting Margin To Numeric Value Solved For Me

*before*

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'margin_left' => '7em',
        'margin_right' => '7em',
        'margin_top' => '7em',
        'margin_bottom' => '7em',
    ]);
```

*after*

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'margin_left' => '7',
        'margin_right' => '7',
        'margin_top' => '7',
        'margin_bottom' => '7',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I was using the function `writeText` passing `x` and `y` as empty string, before with old mpdf version and php 5.6 it was working. Now I changed it to use zero instead.